# Spotipy Accessing Track Data No Longer Works

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have been working on an AI project using `Spotipy` and the `Spotify Web API`. I have been getting a list of preview_url's to do some analysis on and I have successfully gotten many, but I ran into issues lately. Whenever I try to use `.track(track_id)` it gets stuck on the line and doesn't continue past the line. I was thinking it could be an issue with the API, but other commands work fine, it's only track that is giving me issues. I cannot figure out the issue because it doesn't give me any errors, it just gets stuck trying to execute that line and never finishes.
Refreshing the client secret does nothing now. This is the code I have so far.

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials 
cid = '121e03d3acd1440188ae4c0f58b844d4' 
secret = '431a5e56bcd544c3aefce8166a9c3703' 
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

number = 2
output_file = open('data\\25k_data_preview\\track_url_preview_' + str(number) + '.txt', 'a')
for l in open('data\\25k_data\\track_url_' + str(number) + '.txt'):
    line = l.replace('\n','')
    print(line)
    try: 
        track = sp.track(line)
        try:
            testing = track['preview_url']
            if testing != None:
                output_file.write(line + " " + testing + "\n")
        except:
            x = 0
    except:
        x = 0
        
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Are you refreshing your access tokens? Can you provide any code?